# Displaying images on localreport

Tags: c#, wcf, reporting-services, localreport

I have a test system which contains a winforms client application talking to a wcf service which allows me to print of reports depending on the criteria the user selects.
On the wcf side we have a few rdlc files in which we are trying to show some images. We generate the images and save them to disk and pass the filepath of the image as part of a dataset in the datasources.
The following code generates the images

```
var image = Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(barcode, 2, true);
var imageFilename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("{0}.bmp", imageId));                
image.Save(imageFilename);
```

To create my dataset I have the following

```
var rmDS = new List<object>()
{
    new TestObj()
            {
                Barcode = GenerateBarcode(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()),
            },                
};

return rmSpecialDeliveryService;
```

And I added this to the report datasources. When I try to render the report I get the following warning message

```
Warning: Images with external URL references will not display if the report is    
published to a report server without an UnattendedExecutionAccount or the target 
image(s) are not enabled for anonymous access. (rsWarningFetchingExternalImages)
```

The code I have for rendering is the following:

```
var deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";            

Warning[] warnings;
m_streams = new List<Stream>();
report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
foreach (var stream in m_streams){ stream.Position = 0; }
```

Any help would be greatfully appreciated!!!

Comment: I forgot..in the report I have an image control with the following expression set                                                             '="file:///" & Fields!StartBarcode.Value'

Comment: When the report is pulled down to the client then it is will ask for access to images. And if at that time, after rendering, you do not have access to the resources then you will get a blank or other errors.

Answer (score 0):

5 years later...

I was having this same problem today and had to set up an Execution Account within the Reporting Services Configuration Manager on the server where SSRS is running. Ostensibly this was needed because whatever default account the SSRS renderer was running as didn't have rights to access the image I was using. After adding a domain account with rights to access the image and restarting SSRS, my report is now working.